# Missing Database Mail Configuration Wizard in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, database-mail

I was able to verify that Database Mail is installed and running but when I expand the management folder there is no Database Mail Configuration Wizard.

The login is a sysadmin.  I am very green to using SQL but I have to fight my way through this first project before I can step back and actually learn it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.  I found that I was unknowingly running Express.  I had incorrectly assumed the Express designation would be more visible withing the initial result of the @@version query

- In SSMS run the SELECT @@version query
- Grab the column edge and drag it all the way to the right. Within the copyright information it will list Express.

From what I am finding online there are features of Database mail that exist in Express and that is why I was able to enable and run it.